# Storing integers from text file to an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, file-io

I have a task to assign integers from a text file to an array in python.

I tried reading by lines and splitting, but none worked.

The task goes like this: we have an array

```
1 4 5 7 3 2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 6 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 9 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and this needs to be assigned to an array x in order to use it in further functions.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please familiarize yourself with [ask] and the [help]. Note, "I tried reading by lines and splitting, but none worked." is not a sufficiently clear problem description. Show us *what you tried* and *how it failed*.

Comment: do you have this extra newlines in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like:

```
with open('my_raw_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    all_file = file.read().strip()  # Read and remove any extra new line
    all_file_list = all_file.split('\n')  # make a list of lines
    final_data = [[int(each_int) for each_int in line.split()] for line in all_file_list]  # make list of list and convert to int 
    print(final_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind numpy arrays and pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
integers = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
```

Comment: It does not recognize pandas, gonna google about it, thanks!

Comment: you can install it by `pip install pandas`. Also, I just fixed the import statement